# How much would it cost to make this magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

How much would it cost to craft a magic item that bestows the effects of a level 3 spell whenever it is worn? The item can be something simple, like a ring or an amulet; its nonmagical properties aren't important.

Comment: http://therafimrpg.wikidot.com/girallon-s-blessing

sorry for the incorrect spelling, its a level 3 caster level 5 spell, but the more that im looking at it it may only be a 3.5 spell, so i guess the revised question would be what does a level 3 caster level 5 spell cost?

Comment: Please actually revise the question then. :) (Yes, Girallon's Blessing is not a D&D 5e spell.)

Comment: i went ahead and revised it

Comment: yes 5e, sorry ive never used stackexchange before

Comment: No apologies necessary--we just need to understand your actual question. So are you saying "how much would it cost to craft an item in 5e which has this spell from [other system]?" Because I think that's answerable =)

Comment: ok i revised again to hopefully make it more clear

Comment: bestow the effects semi-permanently (I.E whenever im wearing it), and preferably the extra arms would be there whenever the ring is on.

Comment: ok my bad and i will do just that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The guidelines (they're not hard rules by any stretch of the imagination) for creating new magic items appear on page 284 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*.

The table "Magic Item Power by Rarity" advises that items creating a 3rd-level spell effect once per day are at least Uncommon.  However if the effect is continuous, the advice is that the item rarity should be much greater -- no less than Rare.  Assuming the 3rd-level effect to be a least a step above this baseline, it would be at least a Very Rare item.

The suggested price range for Very Rare items (DMG page 135) is 5,001-50,000 gp.  The cost for crafting them (DMG page 129) is 50,000 gp and 2,000 days (5½ years) of work. It's suggested that characters should be roughly level 11 before the GM introduces items of this potency.

Comment: yeah I read through that page already and had determined that also, I just wanted confirmation that I was interpeting it correctly.